# syntax error: operand expected (error token is “:prev”)

Tags: bash

I am having difficulty  trying to get my bash code working. I am using macosx yosemite as my os. i have copied the code here that is giving me trouble. I think their is an an issue with `while`.

Here is my code:

```
# i sorry for length code
while [[ "$house" -ne "1" && "$house" -ne "2" && "$house" -ne "3" && "$house" -ne "4" && "$house" -ne "5" && "$house" -ne "6" && "$house" -ne "7" && "$house" -ne "8" && "$house" != ':prev' && "$house" != ':preV' && "$house" != ':prEv' && "$house" != ':prEV' && "$house" != ':pRev' && "$house" != ':pReV' && "$house" != ':pREv' && "$house" != ':pREV' && "$house" != ':Prev' && "$house" != ':PreV' && "$house" != ':PrEv' && "$house" != ':PrEV' && "$house" != ':PRev' && "$house" != ':PReV' && "$house" != ':PREv' && "$house" != ':PREV' ]];do
    house=
    echo 'what is your colour house?'
    echo
    echo "1-red"
    echo "2-blue"
    echo "3-grey"
    echo "4-cyan"
    echo "5-olive"
    echo "6-beige"
    echo "7-mustard"
    echo "8-green"
    read -p " " house
done

# ":prev" should set 'house=', and set 'type=', which is before to go back
# "type" below is my previous menu. its very much of similarity
# "continue" below is for the continuation of my "while" loop
# i must use "else if" instead of elif due to limitations of yosemite, i believe. i switch to elif earlier and had a negative response
if [[ "$house" == ':prev' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':preV' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':prEv' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':prEV' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':pRev' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':pReV' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':pREv' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':pREV' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':Prev' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':PreV' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':PrEv' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':PrEV' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':PRev' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':PReV' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':PREv' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
else if [[ "$house" == ':PREV' ]];
then 
    type=;
    house=;
    continue;
fi;fi;fi;fi;fi;fi;fi;fi;fi;fi;fi;fi;fi;fi;fi;fi
```

I get `syntax error: operand expected (error token is “:prev”)` if I type that, or other prev. I also type all capitalizations so user no mess up on accidentally, will work either small or big letters; since no case insensitive option.

I really appreciate your help !!

Comment: Use `case` rather than so many `if` statements. Also, you should use `elif` instead of `else if`, then you don't have to have all those `fi` at the end.

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and did not get an error, and I'm running on the same OS as you.  ALWAYS post your entire error message please, including the line number.

Comment: The entire error message is in the title. The error is on line 2 (on here). I use `else if` because I was getting error using `elif`. maybe because of forget to remove `fi`. I try that again and well see. I get error when I type `:prev` or with any other capitalizations.

Comment: I try `elif` with one `fi`, it work for that. still error message appear. I'm trying the below, but none have worked so far

Answer (score 0):

You could alter your menue a little bit to make it more readable and robust.

This should also solve your problem:

```
while [[ 1 ]]
  do
      cat -n color.list
      echo " "
      read -p "Please choose the color of your house, q to quit: " nr

      case ${nr,,*} in
          [1-8])
              house=$(sed -n "${nr}"p "color.list")
              echo "Your house is $house"
              # TODO: Do something with selected color
              break
              ;;
          prev)
              # Break and go back to your privious menue
              echo "Go back to previous menue"
              # TODO: Do something to go back to your previous menue
              break
              ;;
          *)
              echo "Invalid choice!"
              ;;
      esac
  done
```

color.list

```
red
blue
grey
cyan
olive
beige
mustard
green
```

**Explanation**

- `while [[ 1 ]]` runs the menue if a valid option is selected
- `read -p "Please choose the color of your house, q to quit: " nr`
  inputs your choice to $nr
- `case ${nr,,*} in` converts the variable to lowercase so it matches prev,PRev,..
- `cat -n color.list` outputs the file color.list with prefixed numbers
- `house=$(sed -n "${nr}"p "color.list")` reads the selected number from
  the file into your variable $house
- `[1-8])` matches every number from 1-8
- `prev)` matches prev, PREV, prEV, etc (if used with `case ${nr,,*} in`)
- `*)` if input is invalid -> repeat menue

Comment: From Bash 4 you can change the case of a variable with `house=${house^^*}` for uppercase and `house=${house,,*}` for lowercase.  So you don't need to set `nocasematch`, which could affect other comparisons.  Also, `select` might be a better option than reading from a file.

Comment: Thanks @cdarke I've updated the `shopt` part. I did not change the reading file part, because I actually like it ;)

Comment: Is the file name correct in this line `house=$(sed -n "${nr}"p "git.list")`?

Comment: Now it is! Thanks. @Azize

Comment: There's also the `nocasematch` option to make pattern matching case-insensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Consider this valid bash code

```
case ${house,,} in
    ([1-7])
        echo $house;;
    (':prev')
        echo 'PREV!';;
esac
```

${variable,,} is *expanded* to lowercase value of $variable

[1-7] is *expanded* to 1234567.